# how to keep Win8.1 on old dual boot HDD and then add new Ubuntu install on new MSATA ,and get rid of old (dual booted)Linux on old drive?

Tags: dual-boot

I have already dual boot Mint with Win8.1 on old 1tb hard drive for 2 years. all is ok..i want install Ubuntu on new msata drive and remove Mint from old HDD..

Comment: Although the method is the same, Linux Mint isn't supported here. For that reason your question will most likely be closed. That said. you're overcomplicating things if the original Windows 8 was factory installed (=UEFI mode). If not and you deliberately installed Windows 8 and Mint in Legacy mode then the process is more complex.

Comment: no my win8.1 and Mint are uefi mode installed. ehy would it be legacy mode?

Comment: So you're overcomplicating. Again, we don't support Mint (or Windows, obviously). Bye.